# Get rank of user based on levels in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a simple table called XP.

```
Id  User_id    Level
1   0032       12
2   0098       4
3   0013       8
4   0189       31
5   1150       11
```

How would I get the rank of a User based on Level? For example User_id `1150` has 11 levels, he would be 3rd and User_id `0189` has 31 levels, he would be 1st.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to sort data. you should be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to get the rank of a specific user, based on his/her level, then use it in my app.

Comment: Could you specify if you want to know how to do this with a SQL-statement, or if you wanna use C# with LINQ or some other way?

Comment: SQL statement if possible, otherwise LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 'rank' field in the User class and get the data from the database using the Row_Number() for the field...

SELECT [Id], [User_id], [Level], Row_Number() Over (Order by [Level] DESC) as Rank FROM [XP] ORDER BY [Level] DESC

HTH,
Mike